# Flutter: How to change color of hyperlink and add underlining while using flutter_markdown library

Tags: flutter, dart, hyperlink, markdown

I'm using [flutter_markdown](https://github.com/DavBfr/flutter_markdown) library for displaying markdown text, for me hyperlink every time is displaying with the default flutter blue color, I have tried to change ThemeData App colors, but it didn't help, basically what I need is to change color of hyperlink from blue to green and make it underlined.

Is that possible? If not, please advice with some alternative way how to achieve it

I'm using this code:

```
_showMarkdownTestModal() {
    var testMarkdown = '[flutter_markdown](https://github.com/DavBfr/flutter_markdown)';
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (builder) {
          return FractionallySizedBox(
              heightFactor: 0.1,
              child: Center(
                  child: MarkdownBody(
                data: testMarkdown,
                onTapLink: (text, url, title) {
                  if (url != null) {
                    _launchURL(Uri.parse(url));
                  }
                },
              )));
        });
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this:

```
MarkdownBody(
  styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
    a: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
    ),
    // ...
  ),
  // ...
);
```

Comment: ohh, that was not obvious for me, what does it mean 'a' TextStyle, but that works, thank you so much!

Comment: `a` is the html element for a link element, and it is being used here as a way to reference which widgets are links as created by the Markdown widget. In a similar way, you can change the style of `#` and `###` by overriding the style for `h1` and `h3` properties in the stylesheet.

Comment: As an aside, seems like there is no workaround for <u> as the renderer doesn't support inline html.  So I don't think there's a way to underline (non-link) text with flutter_markdown